# problem to read csv file from github by python

Tags: python

I have tried different ways to extract data from github and not able to manage it, although I follow all the suggesion from other internet post. Can somebody help pls?
So my code is as below:

````
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/master/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)```
````

Comment: there is issue with your path. check this path
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv

Comment: The file does not exist anymore.

Comment: `url = 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/raw/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv'`

Comment: You have to remove 'blob' in url.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just wonder how come it works when remove 'blob'